# Algorithm for decoding database like file structure

Tags: algorithm

I am working on an automatic decode tool for a database like file structure. The file consists of a header and a body.
Information that is known before trying to decode the file:
Number of rows
Size of the body

The fields can be the following:

- String : one byte for size, followed by the actual string, not zero terminated
- StringAcii : one byte for size, followed by the actual string, not zero terminated
- OptionalString : one byte as a flag, one byte for size, followed by the actual string, not zero terminated
- OptionalStringAcii : one byte as a flag, one byte for size, followed by the actual string, not zero  terminated
- Number : 32 bits
- Bool : Byte with value 0 or 1

There is also a meta data file for each file which contains the number of columns.

My current approach is this:
Compute all possible column types, but exit early if I find a combination that never can be possible while looking at the first row. Eg column 1 = bool, where value is 4.

For each possible column combination that is at least valid for the first row, try to parse the whole table. If no errors and all byte are consumed at the end we have a possible candidate.

This works pretty well, but it is way too slow if a table has 25+ columns. What would be a better way to address this problem?

Comment: Even though we're not strictly talking regex here (the grammar for a row of _n_ columns is regular, but the regex is going to be hairy), you may find some insight from looking at the research literature around regex derivatives.

Comment: Interesting challenge. Two observations: 1) you may be able to utilize the fact that not all byte values are valid in strings, 2) your definition is ambiguous, e.g. a byte sequence could interpreted either as `OptionalString` or `Bool`, `String`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. Currently i assume that in that case its a optstring, as that is a more common type, but i often END up with more then One valid schema. I do check tif a byte string can actually be a string, but i need some more clever tricks to handle larger tables